Is it posible to have NAT with FQDN on ATP700
I have a Zyxel ATP700 and one static external ip with a subdomain
We would like to know if it is posible to have a nat rule that filters incoming trafic by it's FQDN instead of the ports.
See image for reference
enter image description here

No. NAT cannot operate on Domain names. Most types of traffic do not carry a domain name in their data at all. Only select protocols like HTTP(s) do.
Instead a reverse proxy or load balancer would be required to provide application layer decision making like where to distribute requests amongst the HTTP servers based on domain.

yes, you can use domains in network rules, but you need to understand that for work, domains are converted to ip addresses either at the time of loading the rules(if it is not possible to resolve the domain name to the address, then all the rules may not load), or during work(not all can do this. of the ones i know, only pf in obsd can do this). these are general rules, but the toaster you use may not be able to do many things and may not allow you to do them.
ps: what do ports have to do with it? there are no ports in fqdn.
pps: i think you wanted to ask about something else. i think you need a balancer. relayd from obsd can handle this task.
